# javax.ws.rs.RedirectionException: HTTP 302 Found after performing a POST request in JavaEE

Tags: rest, redirect, jakarta-ee

I am trying to perform a POST request using the following code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
...
Client client=ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget=client.target("http://localhost:8080/blablabla");
try {
    MyResponse rp=webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(rq), MyResponse.class);
} catch (RedirectionException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
client.close();
```

The same request works with RESTer so the address `http://localhost:8080/blablabla` is correct. But when I run the code I get: `javax.ws.rs.RedirectionException: HTTP 302 Found`

Answer (score 0):

The `RedirectionException` provides a `getLocation()` method that you can use to retrieve the redirect URI and perform a new request.

If you are using the Jersey implementation you can add the following property to your `WebTarget`, for performing this task automatically:

```
webTarget.property(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, Boolean.TRUE);
```

It seems that this feature is implementation-specific so you can't do this with pure JAX-RS API.